# Xpath approach in case of large files

Tags: java, xml, xpath

The class you're gonna see right now is the classic approach to parse an XML document via XPath in Java:

```
public class Main {

    private Document createXMLDocument(String fileName) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(fileName);

        return doc;
    }

    private NodeList readXMLNodes(Document doc, String xpathExpression) throws Exception {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);

        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        return nodes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main m = new Main();
        Document doc = m.createXMLDocument("tv.xml");
        NodeList nodes = m.readXMLNodes(doc, "//serie/eason/@id");
        int n = nodes.getLength();

        Map<Integer, List<String>> series = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            nodes = m.readXMLNodes(doc, "//serie/eason[@id='" + i + "']/episode/text()");
            List<String> episodes = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < nodes.getLength(); j++) {
                episodes.add(nodes.item(j).getNodeValue());
            }
            series.put(i, episodes);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : series.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Season: " + entry.getKey());
            for (String ep : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println("Episodio: " + ep);
            }
            System.out.println("+------------------------------------+");
        }
    }
}
```

In there I find some methods to be worrying in case of a huge xml file. Like the use of

```
Document doc = builder.parse(fileName);

return doc;
```

or

```
  Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

  return nodes;
```

I'm worried because the xml document I need to handle is created by the customer and inside you can basically have an indefinite number of records describing emails and their contents (every user has its own personal email, so lots of html in there). I know it's not the smartest approach but it's one of the possibilities and it was already up and running before I arrived here.

My question is: how can I `parse` and `evaluate` huge xml files using xpath?

Comment: What library are you using for XML parsing? You might want to look at the stax parser

Comment: I haven't decide anything...that's why I am asking.

Comment: Stax is a good idea then. As it is a serial parser as opposed to DOM, large files will take less memory to process.

Comment: I've read about it. It's not XPath though. Looks like you need to write a lot of if..else.

Comment: That's true, but it is lighter in terms of memory

Comment: XPath requires that a representation (the XML Infoset) of the complete XML document be resident in RAM. If this causes memory problems, then don't use XPath. .NET offers a good and simple streaming (forward-only) XmlReader. In the Java world one can use the streaning extensions of Saxon.

Comment: fair enough. I'm gonna use what Amit suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the StAX parser. It will take less memory than the DOM options. A good introduction to StAX is at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/stax.html

Answer (score 3):

First of all, XPath doesn't parse XML. Your createXMLDocument() method does that, producing as output a tree representation of the parsed XML. The XPath is then used to search the tree representation.

What you are really looking for is something that searches the XML on the fly, while it is being parsed.

One way to do this is with an XQuery system that implements "document projection" (for example, Saxon-EE). This will analyze your query to see what parts of the document are needed, and when you parse your document, it will build a tree containing only those parts of the document that are actually needed.

If the query is as simple as the one in your example, however, then it isn't too hard to code it as a SAX application, where events such as startElement and endElement are notified by the XML parser to the application, without building a tree in memory.

Comment: The schema is pretty simple. The problem is that at a certain point I'll query for something like /delivery/recipients/new_recipient. I'll have a shitload of new_recipients, some customer has something like 300k recipients for a size of 3GB. I would like a system that allows me to ask for a specific query but read it like a stream so I can control the memory overload.